EDMX diagram missing 90% of tables
Just a small annoyance issue. My EDXM diagram itself is missing almost all the tables. The application still adds them from my database (the additional tables are still in my entity types folder) but only 2 tables actually show up in the diagram.
Previously all 100 or show tables would show up in the edxm diagram. How do I fix this?
Here is my current diagram view:

Only two
But in the model browser, we have over a hundred tables:

Any help is much appreciated!

Hard to tell without knowing what changed in the mean time. I recommend you prepare for the future, move to "code-first from database".

I resolved this by totally deleting the entire .edmx and readding it. Thanks for taking a look

Good day, I'm glad you've found a way to fix this problem . If possible, please post an answer so that others who encounter similar issues can see the solution
